# Vagrant sync folder doesn't work on windows 10

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to sync folders from a windows 10 hosto to a ubuntu guest but I get this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.36
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/sync_workspace
    default: /sync_workspace => C:/sync_workspace
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3`,nolock,vers=3 core /sync_workspace
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant`,nolock,vers=3 core /sync_workspace

The error output from the last command was:

stdin: is not a tty
unknown mount option `nolock'
valid options:
  rw         mount read write (default)
  ro         mount read only
  uid       =<arg> default file owner user id
  gid       =<arg> default file owner group id
  ttl       =<arg> time to live for dentry
  iocharset =<arg> i/o charset (default utf8)
  convertcp =<arg> convert share name from given charset to utf8
  dmode     =<arg> mode of all directories
  fmode     =<arg> mode of all regular files
  umask     =<arg> umask of directories and regular files
  dmask     =<arg> umask of directories
  fmask     =<arg> umask of regular files
```

Here is my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
   config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
   config.vm.synced_folder "C:/Users/rafa/Documents/personal docs", "/vagrant_data/sync_workspace"
end
```

Host : Windows 10
Guest: Ubuntu
Vagrant: 1.8.1
VirtualBox : Version 5.0.20 r106931

Any Help?

Comment: Can you turn on the debug option in vagrant, such as `vagrant up --debug`? My guess the issue is the space in windows folder name. But need prove it with debug logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the [vagrant vaguest plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) and let it install the host's VirtualBox Guest Additions on the guest system and in your case it will update your guest addition

Answer (score -1):

Also try `apt-get update` in your guest OS.

Comment: How do you run `apt-get` in windows?

Comment: Easy. Use Ubuntu inside aka Bash On Windows.

Comment: What you mean? VM?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: wow is possible, so I guess your answer is missing a lot information ;)

Comment: My answer is for topic starter's question, not yours. His guest OS is Ubuntu and it has all info that'll help to solve a similar problem I had time ago.